# awk - Skip Header, Add Columns

Tags: awk

I need to create a script that uses awk to sum the values of several columns that are output by a LSF command. I also need the script to skip the headers in the first line. This is what I have so far, will it work? I'm not sure that it will properly skip the first line and add the others. I would test it, but I do not have access to the LSF machines.

```
bhosts | awk '
    BEGIN { running=suspended=reserved=0; }
    NR < 2 { next }
    (running = running + $6)
    (a = a + $7)
    (b = b + $8)
    (suspended = a + b)
    (reserved = reserved + $9)
    END {
           ...
           ...
         }'
exit
```

Comment: Depends what an `LSF command` is and what it's output looks like. If you can't post sample input and expected output, there's not much we can do to help with that.

Comment: Here is some sample output: http://nuweb12.neu.edu/rc/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/bhosts_nodegroup1.png

Comment: Put `sed 1d` between your `bhosts` command and `awk` to remove the header line, like this: `bhosts | sed 1d | awk ...`

Comment: Not really asking about that though, more about whether my code will skip the first line and whether or not I am adding columns the same way, which should be the same with any other similar use of awk.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't test either. This would be better asked on http://codereview.stackexchange.com, but if you want to do some calculations on every line except the first one:

```
bhosts | awk '
    NR >= 2 {
        running +=  $6
        a += $7
        b += $8
        suspended = a + b
        reserved += $9
    }
    END {
           ...
    }
'
```

Undeclared variables are automatically treated as zero in numeric context, so it's not strictly necessary to declare them.